# Looking for SERIF font with slanted lower-case "e" and lower-case "w" with spur

Tags: font-identification, posters, serif

Looking to find the font that matches this image:

[image]

The quickest (but not accurate) match I have is a font called Elephant (not the sans-serif version), and both Poster and Bodoni also come close to a match. Some distinguishing marks:

- Serif font
- Lower-case "e" with slanted crossbar
- Lower-case "w" with spur
- Lower-case "a" with double-story

Plz let me know if you can help!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You can find matches for that font on [myfont's whatthefont ID website](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)

Answer (score 1):

It's ITC Tiffany, although the thin strokes are thinner than on the digitization. Looks like [the original phototype version](https://www.flickr.com/photos/nicksherman/50564233878/) or a slight modification.

Comment: ITC Tiffany is close but the alignment, for example of the 'e' relative to the 'n' is quite different, and as you suggest, the thin strokes are different. Pretty darn close though.

Comment: When you say alignment, what do you mean? If it's just the spacing between letters, that could easily be tightened up in a headline. In the 70s and 80s ad directors liked to really crunch the letters in headlines together for more impact, it was called "tight-not-touching".

Comment: If you look at ITC Tiffany with an 'e' adjacent to an 'n' you'll see that the right most end of the thin portion of the 'e'  is at a different height when compared to the OP sample. My first comment was ambiguous.

Comment: @fred_dot_u It's **definitely** ITC Tiffany, but the [digitised version](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/tiffany/medium-heavy/) is slightly altered. The example is probably phototypeset in the 1970s.

Answer (score 0):

Californian, and Birka also have slanted e's

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! Please show a screenshot of your named fonts ...